# ransack using ransacker for integer to_char

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ransack

I'm attempting to use the ransacker method to convert one of my fields from integer to string with the following

```
ransacker :invoice_no do
  Arel.sql("to_char(invoice_no, '9999999')")
end
```

I'm using PostgeSQL 9.1 and I've tested doing it manually in psql like below, which works

```
select to_char(invoice_no, '9999999') AS invoice_no from invoices;
```

The error I get when trying to search ransack using :invoice_no_cont is

```
  Invoice Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "invoices".* FROM "invoices" WHERE "invoices"."ledger_id" = 2 AND (to_char(invoice_no, '9999999') ILIKE 0) ORDER BY invoice_no desc LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: text ~~* integer
LINE 1: ...edger_id" = 2 AND (to_char(invoice_no, '9999999') ILIKE 0) O...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
: SELECT  "invoices".* FROM "invoices"  WHERE "invoices"."ledger_id" = 2 AND (to_char(invoice_no, '9999999') ILIKE 0) ORDER BY invoice_no desc LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
  Rendered invoices/index.json.rabl (3.6ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 12.3ms

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid - PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: text ~~* integer
LINE 1: ...edger_id" = 2 AND (to_char(invoice_no, '9999999') ILIKE 0) O...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
: SELECT  "invoices".* FROM "invoices"  WHERE "invoices"."ledger_id" = 2 AND (to_char(invoice_no, '9999999') ILIKE 0) ORDER BY invoice_no desc LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0:
  activerecord (3.2.17) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:285:in `rescue in log'
  activerecord (3.2.17) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `log'
  activerecord (3.2.17) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:659:in `exec_query'
  activerecord (3.2.17) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1262:in `select'
  activerecord (3.2.17) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:18:in `select_all'
  activerecord (3.2.17) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:61:in `block in select_all'
  activerecord (3.2.17) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:75:in `cache_sql'
  activerecord (3.2.17) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:61:in `select_all'
  activerecord (3.2.17) lib/active_record/querying.rb:38:in `block in find_by_sql'
```

**Update**

I'm using invoice_no_cont in an AngularJS view, like so.

```
<td data-title="'Invoice No.'" sortable="'invoice_no'" filter="{'invoice_no_cont':'text'}">
      {{invoice.invoice_no}}
</td>
```

This is passed through a 'GET' request to the Ruby on Rails server invoice#index method which then picks it up and sends it through ransack.

```
 @invoices = Invoice.search(params[:filter]).result
```

Comment: It looks like postgres is complaining that you're comparing a text with an integer. I think your problem is that 'to_char(invoice_no, '9999999') ILIKE 0' part in your query. The to_char gives you a String but you compare it with 0, an integer. Where are you using invoice_no_cont? A little more details would help fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my interpretation of your problem:

1. Your invoice numbers are only composed of integers
2. You have a search field that is using angular.js to send the entered value as text to the server
3. You expect a string to be injected in the search(params[:filter]) method call
4. You used ransacker to be able to handle the params[:filter] that you believe is a string

The thing you forgot is that when you send JSON data back to the Rails server, it parses the  JSON payload. And despite the fact that you think you're returning a string, the json gem parses the value and sees an Integer as described in the [gem's parser documentation](https://github.com/flori/json/blob/master/lib/json/pure/parser.rb#L250).

It means that even if you think you're getting a String, the params hash actually gets an Integer as value for the filter key, and that's what:

```
operator does not exist: text ~~* integer
```

is complaining about. Postgres expects to compare with a string, not an integer.

Easy fix would be to add to_s to params[:filter] in your controller.

```
@invoices = Invoice.search(params[:filter].to_s).result
```

That way you make sure you're always comparing strings together. It is also a good way to be fault tolerant with the input you're sending as filter.

You can also not use ransacker and do something like that in your controller, it might be more consistent with the actual nature of an invoice number, but uglier.

```
@invoices = params[:filter].is_a?(Integer) ? Invoice.search(params[:filter]).result : []
```

Hope this fixes your issue.